# How to unblock an ip adress for ReCaptcha

Tags: php, recaptcha

Using the PHP [ReCaptcha library](https://github.com/google/recaptcha) I started having time outs validating my recaptchas server side while developing on my local machine.

I narrowed it down to a time-out in `ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\Post::submit` where `file_get_contents` is used to hit `'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'`. I found I could replicate the time-out from my CLI with:

`php -r "var_dump(file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?remoteip=127.0.0.1'));"`

On a hunch I changed from my wi-fi to tethering on my phone, and could immediately connect.

This indicates that the google server has blocked my IP. So, is there any way to unblock it?

Comment: Let time pass, probably.

Comment: _waits patiently_

Comment: :) ... oh boy, maybe not then.

Answer (score 0):

There was no solution to this problem. Eventually my IP changed, and I was able to start using recaptcha locally again.

In the end I had to stop testing the recaptcha functionality locally (which is pretty bad). I've started looking for alternatives to recaptcha.